# I'm missing some characters when I'm using UART interrupt method in STM32F407VET

Tags: stm32, stm32f4

I'm using UART1 of STM32F407VE in interrupt mode. The baudrate is 115200.
I'm using docklight serial window to read the UART output. I'm sending 15 to 20 characters at a time.
I have missing characters when I check with the loopback code as seen below.

I tried changing baudrates. But when I increase the number of characters, the same problem persists.
This is my interrupt handler:

```
void USART1_IRQHandler(void) {
  uint8_t data;

  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart1);
  __HAL_UART_CLEAR_FLAG(&huart1, UART_FLAG_RXNE);

  data = (uint8_t)(huart1.Instance->DR); //& (uint16_t)0x00FFU);

  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *)&data, 1, 10);
}
```

Comment: Could be a parity problem. Do you have an example which characters exactly are you missing?

Comment: @Jacek . Same character received is missing in the sequence at some positions.

Comment: Then it's very likely it's a parity problem. Try changing parity on the receiving end and try again.

Comment: @Jacek At both Tx end & Rx end parity setting is 'none'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are receiving a byte and putting that byte in the `TDR` register of your UART. It is probably running at the same baudrate so before a transfer is finished a new receive interrupt is received. The call to `HAL_UART_Transmit` is blocking and will check if a transfer is running. The statement `if(huart->gState == HAL_UART_STATE_READY)` will return `false` and as such will take the `else` path. This will result in a return value of `HAL_BUSY`. Which indicates that no transfer has happend because one was still ongoing.

You'll need to add a circular buffer to fix this. Store the received byte in a storage container from within your interrupt handler and another part of your program needs to check if the storage container is not empty and transmit the contents if it isn't empty. You'll need to disable interrupts when you are updating your storage container because a race condition could occur.

You could also add an end of transmission character to your transfer indicating that it is safe to echo it back to you, and as such avoiding the race condition. `0x04` is a great choice for this if you are using ASCII because it is defined as `EOT` (end of transmission).

Another option would be to use `HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_UART_Receive_IT(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size)` to receive a set amount of bytes in interrupt mode.

The library code for the UART can be found inside: `stm32f4xx_hal_uart.c`. The HAL for the STMs is pretty readable and pretty informing, feel free to look inside. It can help in the future to find other bugs. (ST doesn't always make obvious or cooperative choices in their code)

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you are probably overrunning the USART. To confirm, try it at 9600 baud, and if less characters are dropped, that's your problem. In that case, you need to either use HW handshaking, or add a buffer and don't do the transmit inside your IRQ handler but do transmit in your main loop.

Answer (score 0):

`HAL_UART_Transmit()` is taking an address of where is the data to be trasmitted, as a param. The code says: `transmit what is located at &data`.

But `data` variable is located on a stack, so it become invalid (junk data is possible to show up there) right after exit from `USART1_IRQHandler()` (possibly: during the data transmission is still ongoing).

Just make the `uint8_t data` either global or static variable.
It shall be a moove forward.

Answer (score -1):

Actualy almost everything is wrong here. Do not clear RXNE  flag this way. It is cleared by the hardware when uC reads the data from the data register. Do not use blocking functions in the interrupt handler.

If you use HAL  use Callback functions.

My advice first read the uC documentation and HAL  manual, then start programming.